# Find the branch points and branch lines

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the branch points and branch lines of $$f(z)= (z^2-1)^{1/3}(z-i)^{1/3}~.$$

**My approach**

Clearly, $z=1,-1,i$ are the branch points of $f(z)$. For $z=\infty$, I substituted $z=1/t$ and obtained $$f(1/t)=\frac{(1-t^2)^{1/3} (1-it)^{1/3}}{t}~.$$

**First question**: Is $t=0$ the branch point for $f(1/t)$?

**Second question**: How to find the branch lines from the branch points $z=1,-1,i$?

Comment: $f(1/t)=\frac{(1-t^2)^{1/3} (1-it)^{1/3}}{t^{2/3}}$ should be $
f(1/t)=\frac{(1-t^2)^{1/3} (1-it)^{1/3}}{t}$, so $t=0$ is not the branch point for $f(1/t)$.

Comment: @ts375_zk26 why it is not a branch point? And what about branch lines?

Comment: $(1-t^2)^{1/3}=(1-t)^{1/3}(1+t)^{1/3}$ has two branch points $t=1, -1$. At $t=0$, each branch of $(1-t^2)^{1/3}$ is single-valued, and the same for $(1-it)^{1/3}$. Therefore $t=0$ is not the branch point for $\frac{(1-t^2)^{1/3} (1-it)^{1/3}}{t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $z$ traverses a large circle centered at $0$ encircling all branch points $z=1, -1, i$,
the value of $f(z)$ is \begin{align*}
&\exp\left(\frac{1}{3}(\log (z-1)+2\pi i +\log(z+1)+2\pi i+\log(z-i)+2\pi i)   \right)\\
=&\exp\left(\frac{1}{3}(\log (z-1)+\log(z+1)+\log(z-i))   \right),
\end{align*}
which is its original value. So $\infty $ is not a branch point of $f(z)$.

When $z$ traverses a path encircling one (or two) of the branch points $z=1, -1, i$, 
the value of $f(z)$ will be 
\begin{align*}
&\exp\left(\frac{1}{3}(\log (z-1)+\log(z+1)+\log(z-i))+\frac{2\pi i}{3}\left(\text{ or }\frac{4\pi i}{3}\right)  \right),
\end{align*}
which is not its original value.

Therefore the branch cuts could be made from $-1$ to $i$ and from $i$ to $1$, that is, $[-1,i]\cup [i,1]$.

Comment: +1 for your efforts.